# Implicit Internal Intent vulnerability showing up when Android app is deployed to the Playstore

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-console, android-pendingintent

Recently I have uploaded my android apk on the app store and its been told that the next upload to Google play store will get rejected and we need to check and resolve it. Below is the screenshot of the message:

[image]

They are referring to package name also. Below is the code:

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        cleanup();
        super.onDestroy();
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.test.dummyapp");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Please assist me how to resolve this.

Below is the code where the component is triggered:

```
 IntentFilter restartFilter = new IntentFilter("com.test.dummyapp");
        registerReceiver(restartBroadcastReciver, restartFilter);



private BroadcastReceiver restartBroadcastReciver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          doBindService();
        }
    };
```

Comment: What component should receive the broadcast `Intent`? Has that component registered itself to listen for that broadcast or is this a manifest-registered component? Post the code and/or manifest entry for the component that should be triggered.

Comment: Hi , added the code , please check

Comment: Please edit your question and add the message that you got from the play store. I'm not exactly sure what it is complaining about.

Comment: I have added screenshot for the error, please check my edits.

Comment: OK, The problem is "implicit Intent". You can have a look at my answer, this should solve it.

Comment: And I edited my answer to include another alternative solution.

Answer (score 4):

When you do this, you are broadcasting an "implicit `Intent`". This is dangerous because any app can register to get this (potential leak of information) and any app can also broadcast this `Intent` (triggering your app).

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.test.dummyapp");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

To fix this you can use `LocalBroadcastManager` (it is deprecated, but still works). Using a local broadcast ensures that other apps cannot see your broadcast `Intent` and other apps cannot trigger your app this way.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager

---

As an alternative, you should be able to make the `Intent` explicit by setting the package name:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.test.dummyapp");
intent.setPackage("my.package.name");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Google recommends that developers use Explicit Intents to reach their internal components either by:

Use Intent.setComponent to explicitly set the component to handle the Intent.
Use Intent.setClass or Intent.setClassName to explicitly set the target component.
Use Intent.setPackage to limit the components this Intent will resolve to.

Comment: But not sure when to use which one.

Comment: In your specific case you cannot use `setClassName()` or `setComponent()` because your `BroadcastReceiver` is an anonymous class. You can only use `setPackage()`. However, this is enough to prevent the broadcast `Intent` from being seen by other apps. Or you need to create an actual class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` and use that instead of your anonymous class, in which case you can then use `setClassName()` or set `setComponent()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems really weird to send a Broadcast in onDestroy.  I can't possibly see a use for that, and I can see a lot of problems due to onDestroy being called unexpectedly (rotation, screen size change, etc).

But if you have to do it, use `new Intent(getPackageName())`.  What they're looking for is a hardcoded package name like that.  The problem is that if you run 'com.facebook.whateveritscalled' and a piece of malware is installed that named itself that, you would be sending the intent to it.  Which if you have extras in the intent could be leaking information to it.

Comment: Above is the code answer for the vulnerabilty. Could you confirm if that is what you meant by getPackageName().

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information.

I made some changes to the posted code. Let me know if this works fine.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    cleanup();
    super.onDestroy();
    openApp((Context) context,"com.test.dummyapp");
}

public static boolean openApp(Context context, String packageName) {
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (i == null) {
            return false;
        }
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        context.sendBroadcast(i);
        return true;
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a launch `Intent` (which is used to start an `Activity`) in a call to `sendBroadcast()`.